# Spark-cassandra join: Pool is busy no available connection and the queue has reached its max size 256

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to join a dataframe using joinWithCassandraTable function.
With the small dataset in non-prod everything went fine and when we go to prod, due to the huge data and other connections to cassandra, it has thrown exception as below.

```
ERROR [org.apache.spark.executor.Executor] [Executor task launch worker for task 498] - Exception in task 4.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 498)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /<host1>:9042 

(com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.BusyPoolException: [/<host3>] Pool is busy (no available connection and the queue has reached its max size 256)),  Pool is busy (no available connection and the queue has reached its max size 256)),
```

We have the same code in cassandra connector 1.6 which worked absolutely fine. But, when we upgrade spark to 2.1.1 and spark cassandra connector to 2.0.1, it had given these issues.

Please let me know, if you faced similar issue and what could be the resolution.

Code we used:

```
ourDF.select("joincolumn")
      .rdd
      .map(row => Tuple1(row.getString(0)))
      .joinWithCassandraTable("key_space", "table", AllColumns, SomeColumns("<join_column_from_cassandra>"))
```

Spark Version: 2.1.1
Cassandra connector version: 2.0.1

Regards,
Srini

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Tune this parameter in your spark conf.

`spark.cassandra.input.reads_per_sec`

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/reference.md#read-tuning-parameters

Comment: That would not fix the issue. By default this configuration has been set to very hight. There is a fix in 2.0.6 that solved this issue as per datastax community

Comment: Can you add the bug link here ?